# Nodejs console.log as callback in forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was having a hard time debugging the output of:

```
content.forEach(console.log);
```

`content` is an array of Strings. The problem was it seemed to log out the entire `content` variable once for every element in the array.

When I finally changed it to

```
content.forEach(function(a){ console.log(a) });
```

It began working. What devilry is this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you were facing?

Comment: [].forEach() passes it's callback three things, not just the one string value; you also get the current index and the whole array as parameters 2+3

Comment: I think he is getting illegal invocation Error for the first i guess.

Comment: @sathyaNarrayanan: in node.js, the console methods are bound to `console`, unlike the browser, so the naive passing works instead of throwing. now if only chrome/ff would do the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array.forEach passes the callback three values:

**currentValue**: The current element being processed in the array.

**index**: The index of the current element being processed in the array.

**array**: The array that forEach is being applied to.

Console.log prints out all of the parameters, not just the first one.